# add filter by attribute on product listing page in magento?

Tags: magento, attributes, filter

I have Added a drop down attribute ring type and add all option from Manage attribute and assigned attribute set.

I want to use this attribute as a filter on product listing page like sort by.

like this site :http://www.reeds.com/Rings-cat6.html
thanks

Comment: Questions about Magento administration are off topic for Stack Overflow. Please use the Magento forums for these. Question such as this one where you are asking the community to provide a complete solution without any evidence of having attempted this yourself (i.e. with code samples etc) are also considered off topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I can't give you a full solution because what you want is is in magento. It's called layered navigation.
When you set an attribute you can specify if it's used in layered. So when you go to a category where you have multiple product sets in place layered navi takes care and ofer you navigation options. It is in fact a filter box where you can decide what you want to see.
To have a better understanding of what I'm saying check those links:

[magento demo store](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/electronics)

[magento layered navigation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/layered-navigation)

[magento wiki product attributes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute/index)